# Solving the integral which shows the second moment of subtracting two Beta-distributed Random Variables

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, random-variables, expectation

Peace be upon you

In my project I needed to find the second moment of the subtraction of two Beta-distributed random variables. I have computed it and reached to the following integral which I should analytically solve
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1} z^2 \int_{max(z-1,-1)}^{min(z,0)} (z-y)^{a-1} (1-z+y)^{b-1} (-y)^{c-1} (1+y)^{d-1}  dy dz
\end{align*}
Or equally
\begin{align*}
&\int_{-1}^{0} z^2 \int_{-1}^{z} A(x,y;a,b,c,d) ~ dy dz + \int_{0}^{1} z^2 \int_{z-1}^{0} A(x,y;a,b,c,d) ~ dy dz,\\
&A(x,y;a,b,c,d) = (z-y)^{a-1} (1-z+y)^{b-1} (-y)^{c-1} (1+y)^{d-1}
\end{align*}
I have attacked to this problem by miscellaneous techniques; I have tried to divide and conquer; I have used by part integration; I have tried to convert it to a PDE system and solve it... But it seems a little more complicated than it looks like.

Any idea for uprooting this old tree?

---

Note: how I reached to the integral?

we should find the density function for $X-X_2$. We know that they are Beta-distributed RVs and the Beta distribution pdf is
\begin{align*}
f_{X}(x) = \frac{x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1}}{Β(a,b)}~,~~~~x\in[0,1]
\end{align*}
Also we can suppose the $-X_2$, by another Random Variable Y which its pdf is
\begin{align*}
f_Y (y)=\frac{(-y)^{c-1} (1+y)^{d-1}}{Β(c,d)}~,~~~~y\in[-1,0]
\end{align*}
We name $X-X_2$, by another random variable $Z$ and since these RVs are independent, the pdf of Z_(p,i,k) would be the convolution of the two above pdfs
\begin{align*}
f_Z (z)&=f_X (x) * f_Y (y)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X (z-y) f_Y (y) dy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(z-y)^{a-1} (1-z+y)^{b-1} (-y)^{c-1} (1+y)^{d-1}}{Β(a,b)Β(c,d)} dy
\end{align*}
Regarding the domain of the two pdf(s) we can write
\begin{align*}
f_Z (z)=\frac{1}{Β(a,b)Β(c,d)}\int_{max(z-1,-1)}^{min(z,0)}(z-y)^{a-1} (1-z+y)^{b-1} (-y)^{c-1} (1+y)^{d-1} dy
\end{align*}
But, we need $\mu_2' (Z)$ which is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{Β(a,b)Β(c,d)}\int_{-1}^1 z^2 \int_{max(z-1,-1)}^{min(z,0)}(z-y)^{a-1} (1-z+y)^{b-1} (-y)^{c-1} (1+y)^{d-1} dy~dz
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't understand something: the expected value of two beta distributions is known. IF $X\sim Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ then $E[X]=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$. So if $Y\sim Beta(\alpha', \beta')$ it follows from the linearity of $E$ that $E[X-Y] = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}-\frac{\alpha'}{\alpha'+\beta'}$. What exactly did you mean?

Comment: 1- I imposed the changes. I meant the second moment and not Expected value.
2- Upon what you suggested I smell good news! because the $X$ and $Y$ are independent (and therefore uncorrelated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the variance one has
$$Var(X\pm Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) \pm 2Cov(X,Y)$$
so if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, i.e. $Cov(X,Y)=0$ (which does not mean independent, but if they are independent then they are uncorrelated) then
$$Var(X-Y) = Var(X)+Var(Y)$$
and hence
$$E[(X-Y)^2] = Var(X)+Var(Y) + E[X-Y]^2$$
if you look at wikipedia, having $X\sim Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ and $Y\sim Beta(\alpha',\beta')$ then
$$E[(X-Y)^2] = \frac{\alpha \beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}+\frac{\alpha' \beta'}{(\alpha'+\beta')^2(\alpha'+\beta'+1)} + \left(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta} - \frac{\alpha'}{\alpha'+\beta'}\right)^2$$